# How often does Xcode5 continuous integration poll for new commits?

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode5, osx-mavericks, osx-server

I've setup a few Bots on Xcode5 continuous integration on OS X Mavericks Server. When I manually run Integrate everything works fine. However, I have the *Schedule* field set to *Poll for new commits* but I have yet to see any bots run, even though I have made commits.

How often does Xcode5 continuous integration poll for new commits?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should be every 5 mins.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/
Session 412 - **Continuous Integration with Xcode 5**

Comment: Huh. I read the PDF and didn't see that mentioned. Do you remember where-ish the 5 minutes is stated in the video so I can't have to watch the entire thing?

Comment: Can't see any mention of this in the transcript for session 412... I was there and don't recall this either. http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/412

Comment: "Should be" being the operative words in that sentence. I recall this being said, but in all of my uses of Bots, I've never seen one poll for commits. I'm reasonably confident that it's broken in it's current release.

Comment: we have been using xcode server bots for about 3 months now, and can say that it HAS, in fact, Polled for new commits correctly and automatically ran an integration build. **BUT** it seems to mess up every week or so, where it wont catch new commits. Can run manual integration, works. Not sure but it does seem a little picky/cranky/broken. Remaking a new Bot usually works but is not ideal.